# In Kotlin, is there a safe way to do ObjectInputStream.readObject?

Tags: kotlin

When I do

```
object_input_stream.readObject() as HashMap<Int, Int>
```

Intellij complains that it's an unsafe cast from `Any!`. Is there a safe way to handle reading from `ObjectInputStream`?

Using `as?` shows a warning as well:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no type-safe way to do this, as the compiler has no way to know what type of object the stream contains.

You've told it that it should be a `HashMap<Int, Int>`, but it only has your word on that.  What if (e.g. due to a bug) you're wrong?  That would lead to a ClassCastException at runtime.  The warning is to alert you to that possibility.

How you handle that possibility is up to you.  The obvious options are:

- Use `as?` to safe-cast it to a nullable value (and then either test for or handle the null),
- `catch` the exception (and then take appropriate action), or
- Deliberately let the exception be thrown up to the caller (in which case you should at least document it, e.g. with a `@Throws` annotation).

Comment: Since generics are erased, `as HashMap<Int, Int>` will succeed even if types were not <Int, Int>, error/exceptions will be thrown at the time when one try to pull data from the Map. Best option would be to have try-catch with testing of one of the value from entries (but one should always specify correct types).

Comment: Even testing one value won't give any guarantee.  (It could be a `HashMap<Any, Any>`, and by chance the first value you pull out could have `Int`s.)  — The safest option would be to (safe-)cast to `HashMap<Any?, Any?>`, and then (safe-)cast the values you pull out of it to `Int`; both casts would be unchecked, but the compiler would warn you.  The alternative would be to cast to `HashMap<Int, Int>`, which would let you avoid later casts, but leave you open to ClassCastExceptions later on without any compiler warnings.

Comment: `and then either test for or handle the null` How does that help? What if it's non-null of a different type?

Comment: @MaxB `as?` gives a null if the value isn't of the required type.  You can then handle that with any of Kotlin's tools for handling nulls (`?.` safe-calls, `?:` substitution, `if()` checks, etc.).

Comment: Using `as?` shows the same warning (please see the edit)

Comment: Yes, but it won't give a ClassCastException at runtime.